# Button color adjustment by data(Ionic2)

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a json database.I want the different Id to have different colors.If Id = 1, get the button blue.If Id = 0, get the button red.Do you have any idea how I can do it.

[image]

**home.html**

```
      <ion-header>
       <ion-navbar>
         <ion-title>
           Ionic Blank
         </ion-title>
       </ion-navbar>
     </ion-header>


     <ion-content padding>
         <ion-list >
           <ion-item *ngFor="let item of getdata">
              {{item.name}} {{item.id}}
         <button ion-button round class="ilanbtnn" >{{item.surname}</button> 
            </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
     </ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
     import { Component } from '@angular/core';
     import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
     import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http';
     import {DataService} from '../../app/dataapi/data-api.service';

    @Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
     templateUrl: 'home.html'
     })
     export class HomePage {

      getdata : any;


      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ,public http:Http,public 
     dataApi:DataService) {

    }

     ionViewDidLoad() { 

       this.dataApi.getVideo().then(data =>
        this.getdata = data);   
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the color based on the id by using the attribute binding:

```
 <ion-content padding>
         <ion-list >
           <ion-item *ngFor="let item of getdata">
              {{item.name}} {{item.id}}
         <button [color]="item.id === 1 ? 'custom-blue' : 'custom-red'" ion-button round class="ilanbtnn" >{{item.surname}</button> 
            </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
     </ion-content>
```

Please notice that `custom-blue` and `custom-red` must be part of the `colors` array from the `variables.scss` file:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,

  //...

  custom-blue:    #387ef5,
  custom-red:     #f53d3d
);
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I wouldn't advise to add too much to the $colors array at moment, as every component in ionic will be generated in every colour in the array. Might not matter much for a native app but it results in a pretty big main.css for a web app.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @rory_za (I wasn't aware at all). Just like you say, every performance improvement we can add to the app, could make the difference to the end user. Thanks again for your comment :)

Comment: Here is the github issue if you would like to subscribe and be notified once anything changes: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/506